# css problems with opera when img is set to display:block

Tags: css, opera

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/js5Pk/embedded/result/).

I have been trying to solve this problem for a while but I cant seem to find a good solution. The problem is that the main `img` in the center takes up a lot of height then it is supposed to do with Opera. But there is no such problem in other browsers.

Sure floating it will solve this but it creates more problems under the image (code that I have not included).

One other solution is to not set `#mainImg` to `display:block`; but that also creates some height/width problems.

So the question is, is there a better solution for this? And why is Opera rendering it differently then the other browsers, what is causing this?

Comment: Why do you need to display the `img` as block? What kind of problems do you get by not displaying `img` as block?

Comment: If you take off display:block from the css you will notice that in the sidebar there will be some extra space under each image, I thought I saw that extra space under the #mainImg but now that I check again there is none. But I still wonder why opera renders it differently

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948145/unwanted-spacing-below-images-in-xhtml-1-0-strict for why you get the extra space below images (and how to fix it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera somehow expands the image's parent block because of the float near it. It sure needs a better investigation, but as a quick fix you can:

- add `overflow:hidden` to `.to_thirds` block: http://jsfiddle.net/js5Pk/1/
- or add `display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;` to it: http://jsfiddle.net/js5Pk/2/

The point is to clear the flow context for this block so the right float won't somehow be placed in it.